# find and replace image urls in wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, amazon-s3

I've recently moved all my wordpress media to aws s3

How can I update all image paths for all my posts?

I have this:

```
<img src="http://my.site/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/image-021.jpg" />
```

I need to change it to:

```
<img src="http://mybucket.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/15000207/image-021.jpg" />
```

you can see that these paths a bit different

```
uploads/2016/02/image-021.jpg
```

and

```
uploads/2016/02/15000207/image-021.jpg
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: okay, so '15000207' this part is common for all the images, right?

Comment: Did you got any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin https://ve.wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/ and search and replace the paths

Comment: for one file - yes, for 5000 -no. Aws s3 adds extra path to each image.

Comment: okay, so '15000207' this part is common for all the images, right?

Comment: that's the problem, for each image this number is different